# How to store, program and execute internal jobs?

Tags: java, spring

I am looking for a way to store system processes / tasks that the application will then execute according to the specified system-wide conditions. The point is that the system should check the input variables and trigger specific actions in the system according to the rules of the process.

I am probably looking for some form of meta-language that I can write rules / actions and that can be programmed to start and stop based on input system parameters.

- In what format record such processes?
- How to parse these jobs?
- What design patterns apply to this?
- Are there any existing solutions on this use-case?
- Which Java libraries to use for this.

If anything is unclear, I will gladly complete the question.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Spring Batch. It introduces it's own domain language for jobs and allows configure them both using XML or java.

Here are couple of examples from their [reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/index.html).

XML config:

```
<job id="footballJob">
    <step id="playerload" next="gameLoad"/>
    <step id="gameLoad" next="playerSummarization"/>
    <step id="playerSummarization"/>
</job>
```

Java config:

```
@Bean
public Job footballJob() {
    return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("footballJob")
                     .start(playerLoad())
                     .next(gameLoad())
                     .next(playerSummarization())
                     .end()
                     .build();
}
```

Spring Batch provides functionality for repeating or retrying failed job steps as well as for parallel steps execution.

For some tasks also Apache Camel can be used. It although provides its own DSL and both XML and Java configuration options.

Both frameworks provide abstractions for description of sequence of actions, which should be done during the job. Apache Camel is more convenient for jobs which require some integration tasks (sending messages in JMS queues, calling REST- or Web- services, sending emails etc). Advantage of Spring Batch is ability to configure application behavior in case of an error or temporary inaccessibility of a service, which should be called (repeat / retry mechanisms). Both frameworks can be integrated with each other: you can call Spring Batch jobs from Apache Camel routes or initiate Apache Camel routes from Spring Batch jobs.

Most complicated solution would be usage of some BPMN engine (e.g. Camunda, Apache Activiti, jBPMN), but that probably would be an overkill.